# wrap function in javascript by curry

Tags: javascript

consider the following JS code:

`var firstFunction=function (x+y) { return (x+y)*.1 ;}`

now create another function "Call" which is method of p.

Assume that result of executing wrap is a function.

`var SecondFunation=firstFunction.Call(1,2).`

when called with secondFunction it should return 0.2.

Like bind ,the arguments to "Call" are stored in the function returned by "Call"

and the function wrraped (here its firstFunction) is evaluated when the function returned by "Call" is called.

How to write method "Call"?

Comment: your first js code is not valid

Comment: could you please explain what is missing here. I am trying this question from one textbook.

Comment: given an answer according to my understanding of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var firstFunction = function (x,y) { return (x+y)*.1 ;}
    firstFunction.Call = function(x,y){
      return function(){
                  return firstFunction(x, y);
      };
     }
    var secoundFunction = firstFunction.Call(1,2)
    var result = secoundFunction();

    console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Could you please tell me why you have returned 
                   "return firstFunction.call(x, y, 0) " with 0;

Comment: I kept x as 0 and y as 2 since only then (x+y)*.1 would be equal to .2

Comment: Nice catch. It was  typo.The correct answer is 0.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use
var secondFunction = function(){return firstFunction.call(null, 1,2);}